# Can't find Java 7 in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio says that I have to download Java 7. I dowloaded it and installed it but Android Studio can't locate it. How do I make Android Studio aware of my Java install?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please include the error message and more information for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Find JDK Installation Directory**

First you need to know the installation path for the Java Development Kit.

Open the default installation path for the Java Development Kit

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

There should be a subdirectory like

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10
```

**Adding Path to Android Studio**

Open your AS and go to File->Project Structure
Then paste the directory path where it says "JDK location"